# Using grep to filter folders with numbers

Tags: regex, grep

I was trying to list only folders with numbers filtering an [`ls -1`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ls) (option `-1` is *list one file per line*) through grep (I know find can do it too, but the sake of this example I want to stick to grep)

Folders are

```
PC:test user$ ls -1
1184
36
69929
7
9907
```

Now this what I get with the different outputs...

This one: I don't get why 9907 is in there, as somehow it made sense only the single digit 7 folder would be?

```
PC:test user$ ls -1 | grep [0-9]
7
9907
```

This is missing 7. Does the `.` mean 2 or more?

```
PC:test user$ ls -1 | grep [0-9].
1184
36
69929
9907
```

Does this mean match everything with a number in there?

```
PC:test user$ ls -1 | grep [0-9].*
1184
36
69929
7
9907
```

When in quotes it just works as I would expect, so why? Is it the equivalent of `[0-9].*`?

```
PC:test user$ ls -1 | grep '[0-9]'
1184
36
69929
7
9907
```

Answer (score 5):

### "filename substitution" or "pathname expansion" or "globbing"

When you type a command, it is subjected to several stages of potential transformation *before* any program (such as grep) gets invoked.

`[` is a special character in some shells.

```
$ echo [0-9]
7
```

What I think is happening here is that the shell is expanding 0-9 as a filename selection and finding your "7" file and therefore passing "7" to grep. Therefore grep is looking for filenames that contain a "7" anywhere in the filename.

If you want `[` to be processed by grep and not by the shell, you have to quote the string or trick the shell into parsing the expression differently.

```
$ echo [0-9].
[0-9].
```

Quoting is recommended.

See also `man bash`  (look for `for`), `man test` and page 151 of [this](https://web.mit.edu/%7Esimsong/www/ugh.pdf)

---

### regular expressions

In a regular expression, `.` means "any single character". So `[0-9].` means any digit followed by a single character. The filename `7` lacks the latter.

---

If you want grep to find single digit filenames you need to anchor your expression to both the start and the end of the line

```
$ ls -1 | grep '[0-9]'
1184
36
69929
7
9907

$ ls -1 | grep '^[0-9]$'
7
```

---

### Oops I destroyed my computer

Careless use of special characters leads to all sorts of exciting results

```
$ ls -1 > x
$ grep *
x:1184
```

This should become clearer if you consider

```
$ ls -1
1184
36
69929
7
9907
x

$ echo *
1184 36 69929 7 9907 x
```

Now just add `rm` and `sudo` to the mix and you can have an experience that might dramatically change your career.